# RabbitMQ server error

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang

UPDATED error message

I am getting a BOOT FAILED error every time I try to start the rabbitmq server. Does anybody know how I can fix this? I have attached the error message. I have tried a few different things including uninstalling and reinstalling it and am now getting a new error message, but am at a loss for what to try next. Any suggestions are much appreciated! Thank you!!

```
BOOT FAILED
===========

Error description:
  {error,
      {schema_integrity_check_failed,
          [{table_missing,rabbit_exchange_serial},
           {table_missing,rabbit_runtime_parameters},
           {table_missing,rabbit_durable_queue},
           {table_missing,rabbit_queue},
           {table_missing,gm_group},
           {table_missing,mirrored_sup_childspec}]}}

Log files (may contain more information):
  /usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost.log
  /usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost-sasl.log

Stack trace:
  [{rabbit_mnesia,ensure_schema_integrity,0,
                  [{file,"src/rabbit_mnesia.erl"},{line,519}]},
   {rabbit_mnesia,init_db,3,[{file,"src/rabbit_mnesia.erl"},{line,450}]},
   {rabbit_mnesia,init_db_and_upgrade,3,
                  [{file,"src/rabbit_mnesia.erl"},{line,458}]},
   {rabbit_mnesia,init,0,[{file,"src/rabbit_mnesia.erl"},{line,99}]},
   {rabbit,'-run_boot_step/1-lc$^1/1-1-',1,
           [{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,488}]},
   {rabbit,run_boot_step,1,[{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,487}]},
   {rabbit,'-start/2-lc$^0/1-0-',1,[{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,453}]},
   {rabbit,start,2,[{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,453}]}]



BOOT FAILED
===========

Error description:
  {could_not_start,rabbit,
      {bad_return,
          {{rabbit,start,[normal,[]]},
           {'EXIT',
               {rabbit,failure_during_boot,
                   {error,
                       {schema_integrity_check_failed,
                           [{table_missing,rabbit_exchange_serial},
                            {table_missing,rabbit_runtime_parameters},
                            {table_missing,rabbit_durable_queue},
                            {table_missing,rabbit_queue},
                            {table_missing,gm_group},
                            {table_missing,mirrored_sup_childspec}]}}}}}}}

Log files (may contain more information):
  /usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost.log
  /usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost-sasl.log

{"init terminating in do_boot",{rabbit,failure_during_boot,{could_not_start,rabbit,{bad_return,{{rabbit,start,[normal,[]]},{'EXIT',{rabbit,failure_during_boot,{error,{schema_integrity_check_failed,[{table_missing,rabbit_exchange_serial},{table_missing,rabbit_runtime_parameters},{table_missing,rabbit_durable_queue},{table_missing,rabbit_queue},{table_missing,gm_group},{table_missing,mirrored_sup_childspec}]}}}}}}}}}

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
init terminating in do_boot ()
```

Comment: just remove all restrictions (recursively) to directory: `/usr/local/var/lib/rabbitmq`

Answer (score 9):

I don't know how rabbitmq works, but the error message looks clear: it tries to delete the directory /usr/local/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@localhost-plugins-expand, and fails because the process has nt the access right to delete the file /usr/local/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@localhost-plugins-expand/amqp_client-3.1.3/ebin/amqp_auth_mechanisms.beam.

Take a look at who is the owner of this file and directory, what are the access right to them.

Comment: On MacOS X it helps me rm -rf /opt/local/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/

Answer (score 1):

This occurred for me during a rabbitmq upgrade with brew.

It was easier for me to just remove the directory all together and install from scratch.

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/var/rabbitmq/
brew uninstall rabbitmq; 
brew install rabbitmq
rabbitmq-server
```

Answer (score 1):

Got this to work. Just delete the database directory and restart server. Note if you had brew installed, database might still be outside Cellar directory. So need to manually delete directory and restart.